# How to connect to Restful Service using mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

I have created a basic Rest Service using MVC Web API. I am trying to connect to the service using MVC 4 right now but am struggling, is this the best way. Does anyone know of a good tutorial to show how to connect to a restful service using mvc 4?

Comment: Might be easier to test with a console application, using `HttpWebRequest` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/), [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/), etc.

You have many ways to do it... you just have to decide which one is better for your specific app.

Hope it helps.